# Open Display preferences programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How to open Display preference programmatically something like below which is for network preferences

```
[[ NSTask
      launchedTaskWithLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"
      arguments: [ NSArray
   arrayWithObject: [ @"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Network.prefPane/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath ]]
  ] waitUntilExit ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate yourself whatever Pref pane that you want open using this

```
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/
```

For Display Preference

```
 [[ NSTask
      launchedTaskWithLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"
      arguments: [ NSArray
                  arrayWithObject: [ @"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Displays.prefPane/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath ]]
      ] waitUntilExit ];
```